# x86_64 nasm jumps to the wrong location

Tags: operating-system, nasm, x86-64

I'm working on code to enumerate the PCI bus, but have found that the jz statement for the loop over each device jumps to the wrong location (not even a label). The register function should be getting called for each time `cmp ax, 0xffff` is inequal, which should be more than once. It is only getting called once.

```
register:                               ; eax = edi = config offset of the function
    mov dx, ADDR_PRT
    add eax, 0x08
    in eax, dx
    shr eax, 16
    mov dx, ax
    call checkpoint
    mov eax, edi
rmsd:   cmp dx, 0x0601                  ; mass storage devices
    je ahci_register                ; register an AHCI controller
    ret                             ; couldn't find it, ignore it


pci_init:
    mov edi, 0x80000000
ilp0:   mov rax, rdi
    mov dx, ADDR_PRT
    out dx, eax
    mov dx, DATA_PRT
    in eax, dx
    cmp ax, 0xffff
    je ilp0c0
    push rdi
    mov rax, rdi
    call register
    pop rdi
ilp0c0: add rdi, 0x100
    test edi, 0xff000000            ; code jupms to the line before this
    jz ilp0
    ret
```

Code is assembled as a PE file and then linked using lld-link and run using EFI.

Comment: `nasm -felf64` version 2.14.02 assembles that code just fine, with a correct branch displacement that targets the `mov rax,rdi` instruction.  (I checked with `objdump -drwC -Mintel` on an object file).  So this is not a [mcve].  (I added dummy definitions for the missing labels/symbols. https://godbolt.org/z/RSdnFY shows NASM 2.13.03 also works, although NASM's asm output for asm is kind lame)  Is something overwriting your machine code before it runs, changing the branch displacement?

Comment: I can't think of anything that should be overwriting it, but I've noted the entire tool-chain just in case.

Comment: Have you checked the disassembly of the final binary, just in case something weird happened in your toolchain?  And live while you're single-stepping, or after the jump to the wrong address?  Are you sure it's the `jz ilp0` itself that sends you there, not some other instruction like the `ret` with a return address that happens to point there for some reason?

Comment: Dissasembly of the final binary shows that it `jz ilp0` jumps to the right place. I called a checkpoint function to figure out where the jump is made to. The checkpoint is only called multiple times if placed after the `add rdi, 0x100` line.

Comment: So why do you think that the `jz ilp0` right before the `ret` is jumping to the `test` or `add` instruction, rather than the `cmp ax, -1` / `je` condition being true when you expected it not to be?  Also, you have a label on the same line as the `add`, yet you have a comment that the code jumps to the line *before* the `test` (i.e. to the add, which has a label.)  But then in the text you claim that code is jumping to an instruction that doesn't have a label.  This is super inconsistent, and it seems like you're drawing bogus conclusions from your data and/or describing stuff wrong.

Comment: No idea what the bug is (the symptoms don't make much sense, unless something is corrupting the code - e.g. maybe UEFI's "PE loader" is trying to modify a global pointer for the purpose of position independence and that's going wrong); but I do wonder if the problem goes away if you comment out the `call register` (which is incomplete and quite buggy - e.g. reading the previously set value in `ADDR_PRT` when it should write to `ADD_PRT` then read from `DATA_PRT`).

Comment: Also note that single-function devices can return the same information (for the function that does exist) for all of the functions that don't exist. You need to check the "is multi-function" flag (bit 7 of "header_type" which is bit 23 of the dword at offset 0x00C in the device's first function's PCI config space) and then only do function #0 (and skip function #1 to function #7) if it's a single-function device.

Comment: The high bit of edi is set, so test is never going to set z. I think you want cmp/jb, rather than test/jz.